# Fatal error: call to undefined function mb_strtolower() in OpenCart

Tags: php, json, opencart

I am using opencart 1.5.6

I had a major server meltdown this week and had to do a mirror restore of the server. Now all is back to normal except now in opencart when I try to login as a customer or go to checkout I get this error and have NO idea how to fix it.

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
>
> **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function mb_strtolower() in **public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_model_account_customer.php** on line **46**

Re-installing opencart isn't an option so I'm stuck on what to do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to install/enable `mb_string` PHP extension. Usually you just need to enable one as mb_string should be shipped with your PHP. See PHP's conf.d or php.ini (depends on used version).

Comment: please explain in brief. i am working on magento 2 framework and php 5.5 version.. but still getting error for mb_string.

Comment: apt-get install php5-mbstring

Comment: $ sudo apt install php-mbstring